# dotnet restore - "not compatible with win7"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am attempting to use `dotnet restore` on a `dotnet core` project, and it seems to work fine until the very end, when I suddenly get this weird message.

> error: System.IO.IsolatedStorage 4.0.1-beta-23516 provides a
>   compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.IsolatedStorage on
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible
>   with win7-x64.
>
> error: System.IO.IsolatedStorage 4.0.1-beta-23516 provides a
>   compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.IsolatedStorage on
>   DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible
>   with win7-x86.

I have searched high and low for answers to this, but I'm totally lost. I've posted my `project.json` below for reference, as well as my `nuget.config` feeds.

### nuget.config feeds

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="aspnet-core" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="api.nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
</packageSources>
```

### project.json

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {

        "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Dnx": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        },
        "net451": { },
        "dnxcore50": {
            "imports": "portable-net451+win7+win8",
            "dependencies": {
                "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        }
    },

    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

## Update

I have cleared the following directories;

`%userprofile%\.nuget`
`%userprofile%\.dnx\packages`
`%localappdata%\NuGet\v3-cache`

Then I ran the updater at `/scripts/obtain/` from the `dotnet/cli/` repository with the following command...

`.\install.ps1 -channel beta`

Then I went back and did `dotnet restore` on my project, it does say that it worked, but I get the following warning.

> warn : Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Abstractions from 1.0.0-rc2-16553 to 1.0.0-rc2-16552

Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: Might be of use https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1141

Comment: I already have that library in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project looks totally fine and it restores without errors:

```
log  : Restore completed in 69790ms.
NuGet Config files used:
    D:\Temp\tempmvc\NuGet.Config
    C:\Users\victor\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
Feeds used:
   https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
Installed:
    279 package(s) to D:\Temp\tempmvc\project.json
```

You might have some newer packages from other feeds in the packages caches or you might be using the wrong version of `dotnet cli`. Make sure you install the CLI from the `beta` channel.

To clear the caches delete:

- `%userprofile%\.nuget`
- `%localappdata%\NuGet\v3-cache`

To install the CLI from the beta feed, run the script from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/install.ps1):

`install.ps1 -channel beta`

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by that last line. I tried that command and it just gave me an error that it didn't exist. Am I supposed to run this on a certain utility, or at a certain path?

Comment: It would have made so much more sense if I didn't forgot the link to the script :) Sorry about that. I've updated my answer

Comment: The link is https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/install.ps1

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel this really should be better documented somewhere. It's quite useful.

Comment: Okay, I think I might have gotten it. I also had to clear out the packages in my `%userprofile%/.dnx` folder. I cleared everything - on the entire computer, related to nuget packages and it worked - though I got a new warning. I'm about to post it.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the question with new information. I appreciate any help you can give, but since it does restore and it does work, I'm going to mark this as answered. Thank you so, so much!

Comment: I've put the new problem in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689380/dotnet-cli-detected-package-downgrade

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is no longer valid with respect to the install.ps1 statement, but I cannot comment there:

The script name is now [dotnet-install.ps1](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.ps1) and the parameters for channel are now: **future**, **preview**, and **production** with production being the most stable.

i.e.

```
dotnet-install.ps1 -channel production
```

EDIT: well for the moment **-channel beta** does still work and **production** does not exist yet, despite being listed in the source code :) the joys of pre-release software...